# Get request python webserver

Tags: python, sockets, webserver

I am trying to make a python webserver listening to localhost on port 8080. So far I can only setup the connection, I don't know how to get the getrequest from the browser? When I go to : `http://localhost:8080/example.txt` it should display the txt file in the browser. But how do I get the get request ?

This is my code so far:

```
host = ''
port = 8080

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind((host, port))
sock.listen(1)

while 1:
    csock, caddr = sock.accept()
    cfile = csock.makefile('rw', 0)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please read HTTP specifications (e.g. [IETF RFC 2616](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) - it's some obsoleted but good for initial reading). Generally, after accept(), you should

- read input until empty line is got (in other words, CRLF CRLF sequence is seen in input)
- split input into lines, combine them to header fields
- process header fields you need to look into for satisfying a request
- read request entity, if any
- form response and send it

For an initial implementation, you can omit dealing with many extended issues as: DoS by request size security, chunked and other non-plain transfer encodings, multiple hosts, etc.

OTOH, if this isn't a homework, better is to use stock BaseHTTPServer module for a concept, and then consider following moving to more advanced implementation.